# How can I prove that $\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}$ is a smooth manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

First, does $\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}$ equals to $[0,2\pi)$?
Second how can I prove $\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}$ is a manifold?

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "equals"? They are different sets, but there is a bijection beetween them (can you give one?).

They are not homeomorphic. The topological space $\mathbf R/2\pi\mathbf Z$ is compact (why?) but $[0,2\pi)$ is not.

In fact $\mathbf R/2\pi\mathbf Z$ is homeomorphic to a well known space, can you find it?

What do you mean by manifold? (topological, smooth...)

Comment: Smooth manifold I mean

Comment: Ok. We can't prove that $R/2\pi Z$ is a smooth manifold since it has no charts on it! But we can define charts and then show that what we obtain is a smooth manifold. But first I think that you need to understand what is the topological space  $R/2\pi Z$

Comment: thank you. But I don't know if my comprehension is right, this quotient topology is consist of [x] where $x \in (0,2\pi] $ ? And prove this quotient topology is one of the problems in the book "An Introduction of manifold"...

Comment: In general, the quotient topology of a quotient of a manifold may not be a manifold. So, you need to exhibit your charts.

Comment: @DuncanRamage I think this quotient is homeomorphic to a circle? But I can't prove that.

Comment: Yes! The map $x\mapsto e^{ix}$ from $\mathbf R$ to the circle induces a continuous bijection from $\mathbf R/2\pi\mathbf Z$ to the unit circle. It is not enough, but if you show that this quotient is compact, then this map is closed and is a homeomorphism

Comment: @Tom If I have already proven that this map is open?

Comment: Ok, then you have proved that it's an homeomophism! I had in mind: "$\mathbf R/2\pi\mathbf Z$ is compact because it is the image of the compact $[0,2\pi]$ under the projection, and a map from a compact to a Hausdorff is closed"

Comment: @Tom but does this quotient is a smooth manifold? Although it is homeomorphic to a circle, and the circle is a smooth manifold?

Comment: Yes. What is a smooth manifold? It's a nice topological space with nice charts on it. If you have charts on the circle, you can carrie them to $\mathbf R/2\pi\mathbf Z$ using an homeomorphism

Comment: @Tom OK I got that, thank you!